# Call Methods of an abstact class child

Tags: java, class, abstract-class, parent-child

I have a class called Router that takes care of interfacing with Retrofit. So in here are all the core methods. Then i have an abstract class called ConfigurableRouter (that extends Router), that allows me to configure my router. Now i want that i can create children of the ConfigurabelRouter (In fact it is an abstract class) with different defults values.

This is an example how it works:

```
Router.configure(M_Rout.class)
            .setPath("close-pi")
            .setParams(params)
            .setRequestMethod(Router.RequestMethod.POST)
            .setIsAuthRequested(true)
            .setCallback(new RequestResponse() {
                @Override
                protected void onSuccess(HashMap<String, String> responseItems) {}

                @Override
                protected void onGeneralError(int responseCode) {}

                @Override
                public void onFailure() {}
            })
           .sendRequest(getActivity());
```

This is how the Router.configure() methods work:

```
public static ConfigurableRouter configure(Class<? extends ConfigurableRouter> aClass){
    ConfigurableRouter configurableRouter = null;
    try {
        configurableRouter = aClass.newInstance();
        //obj is a newly created object of the passed in type
    } catch (Exception ignored) { }
    return configurableRouter;
}
```

And this is an example of a ConfigurableRouter method:

```
public ConfigurableRouter setParams(HashMap<Stthring, Object> params){
    super.setRouterParams(params);
    return this;
}
```

And this is the M_Router class:

```
public class M_Rout extends ConfigurableRouter {
@Override
public String setBasepath() {
    return "www.xxxxxxx.xx/";
}

@Override
public String setInDebigBasePath() {
    return "www.debugxxxxxxx.xx/";
}

@Override
public boolean isDebugging() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public RequestMethod setDefultRequestMethod() {
    return RequestMethod.POST;
}

@Override
public RequestResponse setDefultResponse() {
    return new RequestResponse() {
        @Override
        protected void onSuccess(HashMap<String, String> responseItems) {
            Log.d("RouterLog", "PigSUCSESSSpig");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onGeneralError(int responseCode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure() {

        }
    };
}

@Override
public ConfigurableRouter setAuthToken(String authToken) {
    return super.setAuthToken("tokenExample");
}

public void setIsAuthRequested(boolean b){
    // 
}
}
```

Now my problem is that i cannot acces the non-overriden methods in M_Router class, like `setIsAuthRequested()`, that is in the first snippet. I have no idea how i can do.. tried in different ways but nothing. How can i do?

Comment: if you declare it as type of the parent class, you are limited to the functionalities that parent provides.

Comment: Yeah i know.. But in a project i could have differents class like M_Router, with all different defult values, and not just once

Comment: so don't declare more methods in your abstract method.

Comment: meant to say: so don't declare it as type of your abstract class, or declare more methods in your abstract class

Comment: Yes i have understend it.. So is that the only solution? Nothing else i could do?

Comment: I'll try to summarize it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public abstract class Person {

  abstract void sayName();

}
```

which has two implementations:

```
public class LoudPerson extends Person {

  void sayName() {
    System.out.println("I yell my name!!");
  }

}
```

and

```
public class RegularPerson extends Person {

  void sayName() {
    System.out.println("I will say my name");
  }

  void givesBusinessCard() {
    // whatever
  }

}
```

Now, if you create a method like this:

```
public void handlePerson(Person person) {

}
```

you will be able to call the `sayName()` method on it, because no matter what type of `Person` it is, it will always have an implementation of `sayName()`

Now, let's say you want to pass an instance of `RegularPerson`, and call the `givesBusinessCard()`, this won't immediately work.

1. Even if all you ever pass as parameters are of type `RegularPerson`, the JVM running the code doesn't (can't) know this
2. Someone else could create other subclasses, and change that line of thought.
3. As far as the JVM knows, it's just a `Person`, and all `Person` provides is the `sayName()` method.

Let's say you need to be able to call the `givesBusinessCard()` method, you have 3 options.

1. Alter the method you call. If you need `givesBusinessCard()` to be called, you know it's a `RegularPerson`, so you can say:

   public void handlePerson(RegularPerson person) {

   }
2. Alter your abstract class, add the method there, and provide either a failing or an empty implementation of the method in `LoudPerson`

   public abstract class Person {

   abstract void sayName();

   abstract void givesBusinessCard();

   }

and

```
public class LoudPerson extends Person {

  void sayName() {
    System.out.println("I yell my name!!");
  }

void givesBusinessCard() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not needed here");
}
}
```

or
    public class LoudPerson extends Person {

```
  void sayName() {
    System.out.println("I yell my name!!");
  }

void givesBusinessCard()  {

}
}
```

3. Cast your person to `RegularPerson` before calling it, but make sure to do an instance check:

public void handlePerson(Person person) {
  // ..
  if ( person instanceof RegularPerson ) {
    RegularPerson p = (RegularPerson)person;
    p.givesBusinessCard();
  }
  // ..
}

Comment: This was a perfect explanation, Thank you. I follow the suggestion that you gave me in the comments